# How to add an "image" tag to an mp3 file in Perl

Tags: perl, image, mp3, podcast

I have a set of MP3 files for a podcast, and I'd like each to have an image in it.  I've looked through [MP3::Tag](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MP3%3a%3aTag) but it isn't clear exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `APIC` frame of the id3v2 data. I found a script online that shows exactly how to do this using `MP3::Tag`: http://perl.thiesen.org/scripts/id3image